# Trying to pass a textarea into an Actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been trying for awhile to get this to work but I'm no further then when I started.
I've been trying to create a comment system for my webpage and every works fine however when a comment is created the text area contents does not get passed through to the controller and therefore when the object is made the contents is null.

**View**

```
<p>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="commentContents" value="commentContents" />
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateComment", new { id = Model.Id }, new { commentContents ="commentContents" })

}
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(int Id, string commentContents)
    {
        BO.CommentItem commentItem = new BO.CommentItem(
            Id,
            commentContents,
            (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);

        using (DataLayer.Repository db = new DataLayer.Repository())
        {
            db.AddComment(commentItem);
            db.Save();
        }

        return View();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use a form like this**

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">
     @Html.TextArea("value")
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it this way and it worked. You saved me alot more head ache. For the future if any one looks at this question heres the code I used to fix - <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("CreateComment", "Design", new { id = Model.Id })">
       @Html.TextArea("commentContents")
       <input type="submit" name="CreateComment" value="Submit" />
   </form>

Comment: @User You are welcome..please mark it as an answer, that could be useful for others.

Comment: @user3540625..One more small sugesstion. Please change your name by editing your profile. The Auto generated username looks akward is difficult to refer to someone using this.

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("CreateComment","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="commentContents" value="commentContents" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
   <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>

}
```

action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(FormCollection form)
    {
        string commentContents = form["commentContents"].ToString();
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(form["Id"]);
        BO.CommentItem commentItem = new BO.CommentItem(
            Id,
            commentContents,
            (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);

        using (DataLayer.Repository db = new DataLayer.Repository())
        {
            db.AddComment(commentItem);
            db.Save();
        }

        return View();

    }
```